# Selecting all links (multilinestring) that do not touch current link (multilinestring) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select, select-by-location

I have a network of links (multilinestring) and nodes (point) which is topology of a rail network. I have an issue with the network. There are certain links that are not touching the main network at all and thus are not relevant to my work.

How do I select all the links that are not touching the (main) network?

I have tried using select by location using arcpy but thats annoyingly slow. This code repeatedly runs the command `SelecLayerByAttribute` and selects the touching link. The command is run in a loop sufficient times to ensure there are no other new links touching the network.

Code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('NewLinks_lyr',"NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" = 100) #link with FID 100 is in the main network
for i in range(1,1000):
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('NewLinks_lyr',"BOUNDARY_TOUCHES",'NewLinks_lyr',"","ADD_TO_SELECTION","NOT_INVERT")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('NewLinks_lyr', railway_ln3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Buffer` your lines with dissolve type `All` and a small buffer distance (.5 feet perhaps, depending on the size of your gaps). Perform a `Multipart to Singlepart` on the buffers. Select the singlepart buffer that intersects the main network with a `Select By Location`. Finally, select the lines `within` the selected buffer, or a reverse selection for those that aren't part of the main network.

Comment: When I am working with a really big network with around 260,000 features, the Buffer command with dissolve all is not able to dissolve all the features. Rather, it divides the entire features into 10 parts. Thus, multipart to single part creates several smaller networks. Thus, there is no way of obtaining the big main network. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perform your buffer with dissolve type `None`. Then run a dissolve on the buffers and see if that creates a single part (I also find this faster for whatever reason than buffering with dissolve type `All` - sometimes quite a bit). Otherwise cursors and geometry objects can be a more hands-on approach to combining parts. This is worthy of its own GIS SE question.

Comment: That doesnt work either.
This is what I am using.

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(featureLayer , temp2, "0.5 Feet", "FULL", "FLAT", "ALL")
arcpy.Dissolve_management(temp2, temp3, "", "", "", "")  
arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management(temp3, outputLayer)

Comment: I’d ask a new question for fully dissolving features when the standard tools fail.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of simply running the code 1000 times, use `GetCount` and a `while` loop to end the iteration once all features are selected.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('NewLinks_lyr',"NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" = 100') #link with FID 100 is in the main network
#old count variable
oldCount = "0"
#new count varaible
newCount = arcpy.GetCount_management ('NewLinks_lyr').getOutput (0)
#keep selecting while new features are being selected
while oldCount != newCount:
    print newCount, "features selected"
    #set old count to new count
    oldCount = newCount
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('NewLinks_lyr',"BOUNDARY_TOUCHES",'NewLinks_lyr')
    #set new count to current selection
    newCount = arcpy.GetCount_management ('NewLinks_lyr').getOutput (0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still takes 30 minutes to run. I am hoping the time to be somewhere around 1-5 minutes. I need a completely new approach.